# Would a question about ease of learning certain classes in TF2 be too opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm currently thinking about asking a question about which class in TF2 is easiest to learn for new players, because I think it would be a useful piece of information both for new players and for those trying to get their friends into the game.

Would this question be inevitably too opinion-based for Arqade?

Comment: TF2 metagame, common sense and experience dictate that the skill floor for classes, from lowest to highest, is *somewhat* like this: heavy, medic, pyro, soldier, demoman, scout, sniper, engineer, spy. Note that the sequence for the skill ceiling is completely different, *somewhat* like medic, sniper, heavy, pyro, spy, engineer, scout, demoman/soldier. And in writing this comment I came to unfortunately agree with Frank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately that would be too opinion-based.  The problem is that everyone learns differently, at a different pace, and in a different way.  Any answers we get to a question of that sort is going to be inherently subjective.  Most likely, what we'll get is lots of answers of, "This worked for me", or, "This didn't work for me".  And each person will decide on a different class that's easiest.

That doesn't lend itself well to our skillset.  We have the expertise of gaming, but it doesn't lend itself well to such a subjective question.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case.  Thank you for a very clear answer on the matter.